# how to create a service(amqp) and ingress resource in k8s other than http or https?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, rabbitmq, amqp

how to create a service(amqp) and ingress resource in k8s other than http or https?

We have a requirement  where our java-spring-bot app needs to send request through 443/80 port and we are requirement to receive that request on port 443/80 & redirect it to our rabbitmq pods which runs on amqp protocol not on http/https.

I don't know as of now it's possible or not, but we have created ingress resource with which to redirect request to our rabbitmq deployment/pods.

Here's ingress resource definition.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ing-rabbitmq-amqp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
       paths:
        - path: /amqp
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: rabbitmq-amqp
              port:
                number: 5671
```

But we are making our java app connect to rabbitmq through this configuration we are getting error messages.

From our java-app

```
2023-02-03 07:13:51.031  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2023-02-03 07:13:51.106  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [10.25.119.247/amqp:80]
2023-02-03 07:13:51.125  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Broker not available; cannot force queue declarations during start: java.net.UnknownHostException: 10.25.119.247/amqp



Usually our app throws this messages for successful connection with rabbitmq on port 5671

2023-02-03 07:15:44.087  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2023-02-03 07:15:44.150  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [10.25.119.247:5671]
2023-02-03 07:15:46.182  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#2f01783a:0/SimpleConnection@5b202a3a [delegate=amqp://test_bot_user@10.25.119.247:5671/test, localPort= 58840]
```

While nginx-ingress-controller pod is throwing below error messages.

```
2023/02/03 07:20:08 [error] 4299#4299: *209766772 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while proxying and reading from upstream, client: 10.25.119.247, server: 0.0.0.0:5671, upstream: "192.168.52.60:5671", bytes from/to client:5467/6570, bytes from/to upstream:6570/5467
[5.161.119.202] [03/Feb/2023:07:20:08 +0000] TCP 200 6570 5467 263.959


This is our serverIP: 10.25.119.247
This is rabbitmq-pod IP which is coming in that log: 192.168.52.60
```

So first of all is it possible to create k8s service and ingress resource on other protocols like amqp?

Secondly if answer to first question is No, we can't create those resources in k8s on  protocols http/https and even if we can create but I cannot achieve this scenario then
how do I achieve my scenario where our client is behind a proxy(Cisco-WSA/12.5.2-007) wants our java-springboot app(which connects with rabbitmq on amqp protocol) to connect with our rabbitmq-pods through https ports only and is not willing to open rabbitmq tls port 5671 in his outbound request?

If any queries are there please me know?

Answer (score 0):

i think it won't be possible with Nginx ingress just like that, as it supports the **HTTP** **protocol**.

[Nginx ingress controller doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/)

although **amqp** uses the **TCP** as **transport protocol** implementing  **tcp_passthrough** config on **Nginx ingress controller** might could be successful for you.

**Update:**

> Ingress does not support TCP or UDP services. For this reason this
> Ingress controller uses the flags `--tcp-services-configmap`

So you can expose **one port** on the ingress controller and use it to access the **TCP** **service**.

Create configmap in **ingress-nginx** namespace

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  5672: "default/rabbitmq-service:5672"
```

update **nginx** deployment with **arg** as it is without changing anything

```
--tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
```

and last, add port config in the deployment of **nginx** ingress as shown in the doc.

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

Comment: This is very urgent and I'm currently not very familiar with tcp_passthrough and  how to implement it with nginx ingress controller. If I may, could please share ingress controller example for tcp_passthrough

Comment: shared the answer and doc.